Does sequence produced by Newton's method converge

$\min f=2x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2+2x_1^3+x_1^4$. Given open ball
$B(r)=\{(x_1,x_2)^T:x_1^2+x_2^2<r^2\}$, where
$r=\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6}$, $\nabla^2f$ is positive definite on $B(r)$.
For what starting points $\mathbf{x}_0=(a,a)^T\in B(r)$ does the
Newton's method converge?

I derive the sequence $\mathbf{x}_{k+1}=\mathbf{x}_k-(\nabla^2 f)^{-1}\nabla f$, where $\nabla f=(4x_1-2x_2+6x_1^2+4x_1^3,2x_2-2x_1)^T$ ,$\nabla^2f=\begin{pmatrix}12x_1^2+12x_1+4&-2\\-2&2 \end{pmatrix},(\nabla^2f)^{-1}=\frac{1}{24x_1^2+24x_1+4}\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\2&12x_1^2+12x_1+4 \end{pmatrix}$.
However it is obvious that this method gets complicated soon. I am stuck, but I can't think of other methods. Can anyone suggest other ways?
Thanks!

What does numerical simulation suggest? Did you do projection at each iteration?

You may want to add step size as well.

Have you tried seeing if the conditions for the Kantorovich theorem hold?

I didn't learn that theorem. The question is from my optimization course, they didn't teach the theorem. But I will check the theorem now.

Note that, for all $u, v\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 u\\
 v
\end{pmatrix} - (\nabla^2 f(u,v))^{-1}\nabla f(u, v)
= \frac{u^2(4u + 3)}{6u^2 + 6u + 1} \begin{pmatrix}
 1\\
 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Thus, the sequence just equivalent to
$y_0 = a, y_{k+1} = f(y_k), k = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$ where $f(u) = \frac{u^2(4u + 3)}{6u^2 + 6u + 1}$.
We have $y_k \to 0$.
Thus, $\mathbf{x}_k \to [0, 0]^\top$.
